# Umbraco hook up to load document

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am writing custom property for umbraco that counts hits on document.

Is there any way how can I hook up my logic to page when document is loading?

**Example:**
I have structure:

1. Home
2. - About me

Both have my custom Property.

I would like to record when they have been loaded.

**Note:** I do not want to use any javascript, or actions on page. I would like to have it as one custom DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that I have chosen is:
use IHttpModule as umbraco does not have any event that can be used for this.

As to configuration:
I have decided dynamicaly hook up my module after application start.

Thnx all for considering my question.

Comment: Not sure this would work, since in the HttpModule you would not know the ID of the node being visited.

Comment: agreed with @Digbyswift you have no context in your module therefor you should log the url visited, not the node -- as was his answer in the first place.

Comment: @Digbyswift I do not need context for this, all I need is url and uQuery. This will allow me to get the data for node ID. Using standard umbraco UI do data access required.

Comment: Yes, you can use the uQuery and the URL but it's like using a hammer to crack a nut. Also, this will throw intermittent exceptions because `GetNodeByUrl()` uses the XML cache which won't be available immediately once the application `awakes`, only after. It also won't pick up node url aliases, and will be called for each request passed through IIS.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would to have a separate db table specifically for page hits, e.g. `[PageHit]` which had two columns `[NodeId]` and `[HitCount]`.

A hit on a page either created a new record if no hits had previously been recorded, or incremented the count on an existing record.

You would need to ensure that the hit was recorded per page, so recording it in the your base `Masterpage` or in a base `Controller` would be my approach.

You could then have a property based upon a custom datatype that looked up the hit count for the specific node that the property existed upon. The custom datatype could be a usercontrol, and since in the Umbraco backoffice when you load a node in the content editor the node's ID is in the query of the URL, you can access this in the usercontrol to query the database.

Using a separate table allows you to separate things into a separate DLL too as you would not need to be reliant on the Umbraco API as you could use an ORM like PetaPoco or basic ADO.

I certainly wouldn't write directly back to the node itself as this would cause an unnecessary load on the database, causing latency on the site's page loads and generally slow things down.

Comment: This was my first idea have action on controller.The issue is I cannot be easily plugable and I would need to modify code.

Comment: Actually it's probably easier to do it with a Controller or even with a global filter maybe. This could be registered in a custom Global class inheriting from `UmbracoApplication`, and it could detect `ActionExecuting` events. The one thing you do *not* want to do is save to the node directly for the reasons I explain above.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep this data inside the Umbraco backend, you'd need to create an usercontrol and embed that control in the masterpage (top masterpage);
In the usercontrol add these usings:

```
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory;
```

And a method similar to this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) // don't want to count postbacks
        {
            Document nodeCount = new Document(Node.GetCurrent().Id);
            int Count = 0;
            try
            {
                Count = Convert.ToInt32(nodeCount.getProperty("hitCount").Value);
            }
            catch
            {
                Count = 0; // value == null, not set yet
            }
            nodeCount.getProperty("hitCount").Value = Count + 1;
            nodeCount.Save();
            nodeCount.Publish(new User(0));
            umbraco.library.UpdateDocumentCache(nodeCount.Id);
        }
```

PS this is written without testing.. just of the top of my head

Comment: The issue is I do not want any additional logic in my pages. My idea is it should work out of the box.

Comment: In that case, you can create a HttpModule (and register it in the web.config) with the same logic as above.  A module is an assembly that is called on every request. EDIT: I wonder if you can get the current context (the Umbraco node for instance) for the request handlers..

Comment: -1 @Leon Sorry, saving and publishing the page on each page_load is a awful suggestion. See my answer for the reasons why.

Comment: @Digbyswift I know it's an awful suggestion and it wouldn't be my solution to think of, but since TS wanted it as a property there is no other way to make sure the changes stick. Taking the URL and posting it to a new table (or new database which I prefer -- keep the data seperate from the CMS) is a better solution. But that wasn't the question..

Comment: Sure there is, the property could be a custom usercontrolwrapper datatype that just uses the node id to lookup on the db table. See my answer for a little more detail.